# How to get weighted average price of each item from a set multiple items, into a new dataframe using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a dataframe which includes multiple items and each item has been purchased multiple times with different prices and in different quantities within a year. I need to find the weighted average of each item and map each item with its weighted average price into a new data frame.

```
   Year Article  Price  Weight
18  2013  Cheese   18.0    26.0
19  2013   Apple    5.0     7.0
20  2013     Bun    2.0     2.0
21  2013   Coatl    4.0     5.0
22  2013  Cheese   20.0    21.0
23  2013   Peach   12.0     8.0
24  2013   Apple    4.6     3.0
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = newonly2013

def weightedAverage(df,Weight,Price):
    return sum(df['Weight']*df['Price'])/sum(df['Weight'])

wa=weightedAverage(df,'Weight','Price')

ar = df.groupby('Article', as_index=False).apply(weightedAverage)
print(ar)
```

This is what i tried and failed, would appreciate it greatly if someone could help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With your custom function, only pass `df` as parameter:

```
def weightedAverage(df):
    return sum(df['Weight']*df['Price'])/sum(df['Weight'])

ar = df.groupby('Article', as_index=False).apply(weightedAverage)
```

Or, if you need to be able to pass the columns names:

```
def weightedAverage(df, Weight, Price):
    return sum(df[Weight]*df[Price])/sum(df['Weight'])

ar = (df.groupby('Article', as_index=False)
        .apply(weightedAverage, Weight='Weight', Price='Price')
      )
```

Alternatively, use [`numpy.average`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) and its `weights` parameter:

```
import numpy as np

out = (df.groupby('Article')
         .apply(lambda d: np.average(d['Price'], weights=d['Weight']))
       )
```

output:

```
Article
Apple      4.880000
Bun        2.000000
Cheese    18.893617
Coatl      4.000000
Peach     12.000000
dtype: float64
```

As DataFrame:

```
out = (df.groupby('Article')
         .apply(lambda d: np.average(d['Price'], weights=d['Weight']))
         .rename('average').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
  Article    average
0   Apple   4.880000
1     Bun   2.000000
2  Cheese  18.893617
3   Coatl   4.000000
4   Peach  12.000000
```

Comment: Much appreciated, this should work i believe, thanks!